# Combine some lambda expressions using Or operand

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, expression, expression-trees

I want to make a dynamic expression which will be generated out of an unknown number of `Or` conditions:

```
    IQueryable<Entity> entities = Repository<Entity>.Load();

    Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> wholeFilter;

    foreach(condition in Conditions)
    {           
      Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> filter = e => e.something1 == condition.First && e.something2 == condition.Second
      wholeFilter = wholeFilter.Or(filter)
    }

    return entities.Where(wholeFilter);
```

I tried to implement the `Or` extension but I couldn't come up with a logical way.

Moreover I was playing around the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and wrote something like:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Entity>();
```

and the code below in my loop:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(filter);
```

However I realized that it just `And` the conditions together not `Or` them....

Any idea how to generate the combined expression?
regards

**EDIT :**
the original code that I wrote :

```
public IQueryable<IEntity> Find(IEntityType entityType, List<AdaptiveObjectModelSpecification> queryObjecs)
{
    if (entityType == null)
        return null;

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<IEntity>();
    var entities = Repository<IEntity>.Find(p => p.EntityType == entityType);

    if (queryObjecs != null)
    {
        foreach (var queryObject in queryObjecs)
        {
            if (entityType.PropertyTypes.Count(p => p.PropertyName == queryObject.PropertyType.PropertyName) == 0)
                throw new MissingFieldException(String.Format("Column {0} not found.", queryObject.PropertyType.PropertyName));

            predicate = predicate.Or(e => e.Properties.Any(p => p.Value == queryObject.SearchValue && p.PropertyType.PropertyName == queryObject.PropertyType.PropertyName));
        }
        entities = entities.Where(predicate);            
    }

    return entities;
}
```

generated entities.Expression.ToString() when queryObjects has two elements =

```
{value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Interface.IEntity])

.Where(p => (p.EntityType == value(Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Service.AdaptiveObjectModelRepositoryService+<>c__DisplayClassd).entityType))
// The line below is generated by PredicateBuilder 
.Where(
Param_0 => ((False
OrElse 
Invoke(e => e.Properties.Any(p => ((p.Value == value(Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Service.AdaptiveObjectModelRepositoryService+<>c__DisplayClass10).queryObject.SearchValue) AndAlso (p.PropertyType.PropertyName == value(Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Service.AdaptiveObjectModelRepositoryService+<>c__DisplayClass10).queryObject.PropertyType.PropertyName))), Param_0)) 
OrElse 
Invoke(e => e.Properties.Any(p => ((p.Value == value(Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Service.AdaptiveObjectModelRepositoryService+<>c__DisplayClass10).queryObject.SearchValue) AndAlso (p.PropertyType.PropertyName == value(Azarakhsh.Domain.Core.AdaptiveObjectModel.Service.AdaptiveObjectModelRepositoryService+<>c__DisplayClass10).queryObject.PropertyType.PropertyName))), Param_0)))}
```

Comment: Any reason why you never accept answers?

Comment: Sorry but I assume a practical answer should be marked as "Accepted". right?

Comment: well, am I missing something here? it's all as I expected... no need to mention I definitely vote for a post which is relevant to finding the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Using `PredicateBuilder.Or` should certainly be "and"-ing the results together.

The code you've currently got in the main snippet of code won't compile because you're using `wholeFilter` without assigning it an initial value - and additionally, I don't know of any instance or extension method called `Or` on `Expression<TDelegate>`.

I would stick to `PredicateBuilder`, and work out why that isn't working - because it certainly should. Please post some code using `PredicateBuilder`, along with the SQL it generates.

Comment: public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left , Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
        {
           LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = RebuildExpressionIfNeeded(left.Parameters[0], right);
           return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.OrElse(left.Body, lambdaExpression.Body), right.Parameters);
        }

Comment: sorry for being late. and I'm grateful for your notice. I edited the post, so it's the original one. the result of the query is the very last entity which can satisfy the queryObject. so if there would be 3 match entities, just the last one would be returned... moreover, I can't understand why PredicateBuilder.Or "And-"ing the queries. isn't it supposed to Or them?...

Comment: @Javid_p84: Where has that extension method come from? It's still not clear to me why you think that `PredicateBuilder` is "anding" the expressions, when it's clearly using OrElse in the generated expression. There *are* references to AndAlso, but that's because you're using `&&` within your expressions.

Comment: @Jon : Yes it's obviously using OrElse. however it doesn't return all of the matching entities but the last one. Imagine there are 10 matching entities, the entities from 1 to 9 won't be in the returned list. just #10 .... I guess it doesn't keep the previous results. I'm running into this problem in my unit tests. so I'm sure about the data....

Comment: I could have manage it with Union extension method. but unfortunately it doesn't work in NHibernate 3.1

Comment: @Javid_p84: I suggest at this point you take a *simple* example, and look at the generated SQL.